# How I can pass data in view using Post method and ViewBag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

First view send form

```
foreach p in Model
<form method="post">
 <td class="pricelight"><input type="radio" name="price"value="@p.PriceLight.ToString("")"/>@p.PriceLight.ToString("")</td>
        <td class="fromtabletime"><input type="radio" name="price"value="@p.PriceOk.ToString("")/>@p.PriceOk.ToString("")</td>
        <td class="totable"><input type="radio" name="price"value="@p.PriceHigh.ToString("")/>@p.PriceHigh.ToString("")</td>
         <td class="button13"><button type="submit" asp-action="Buy" asp-route-id="@p.PhoneId" asp-controller="Home">Next</button></td>
</form>
```

Then I need to handle data in post
Controller

```
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Buy(int?id,Order order,string price,@p.PriceLight,@p.PriceOk,@p.PriceHigh)
        {
            string ryt={price};
             ViewBag.price=ryt;
            context.Orders.Add(order);

            context.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.phoneId=id;
            return View("Thanks, " + order.OrderName);


        }
```

Then I want to get it in new view

```
@using System.Linq;
@using System;


@model List<Searchphone>



@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PhoneId";
}


<h2 class="orderinformation">Order Data</h2>
<form method="post" class="formpass">
       <h3> <input type="hidden" name="@ViewBag.price" value="@ViewBag.price" />@ViewBag.price</h3>
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" id="PhoneId"value="@ViewBag.PhoneId" name="PhoneId">
    <label for="OrderSurName">Surname</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Surname" name="OrderSurName" required><br>

    <label for="OrderName">Имя</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="OrderName" required><br>
    <button type="submit" class="button7">To pay</button>

</form>
```

1) I dont get it in view, only in URL. How I can get it in view using Post method?Why does not work viewbag?
2) I want to compare price value with @p.PriceLight from the first view in post method. But how I can pass @p.PriceLight in method?

Comment: ViewBag only lasts for one request. One option is to use the [post/redirect/get pattern](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2011/04/asp-net-mvc-post-redirect-get-pattern/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) I dont get it in view, only in URL. How I can get it in view using Post method?Why does not work viewbag?

You should first debug to check if the ViewBag has a value in your controller action. Since the ViewBag are used in hidden input, you can't directly see it on page, you can press f12 in your view to check if the ViewBag is rendered. I used your codes and can get it in the view.

> 2) I want to compare price value with @p.PriceLight from the first view in post method. But how I can pass @p.PriceLight in method?

The form only submit the checked radio button value, if you want to get the value of PriceLight, define a hidden field in the form in your first view.